# Oracle cpu usage 100% on windows server 2008R2

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper, oracle11gr2

I have Oracle Standart Edition 11.2.0.1.0 single instance on my Windows Server 2008R2.
Today we realise windows cpu usage %100 and nobody couldnt connect to database and work until to restart oracle instance.
When i check alert log i have seeen is belown ORA 600 generic error,

> Errors in file d:\app\administrator\diag\rdbms\zozdbc\zozdbc\trace\zozdbc_ora_1548.trc  (incident=77112):
>   ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [12259], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
>   Incident details in: d:\app\administrator\diag\rdbms\zozdbc\zozdbc\incident

And after when i checked implemented trace file, i have seen as belown error,

> --------Dumping Trigger Sublists --------  trigger sublist 0 :  trigger sublist 1 :  trigger sublist 2 :  trigger sublist 3 : Trigger
>   Owner : zoz_TABS Trigger Name : SIS_USER_DEF_TRGA  trigger sublist 4 :
>
> *** 2017-05-18 10:16:44.437 Incident 77112 created, dump file: d:\app\administrator\diag\rdbms\zozdbc\zozdbc\incident\incdir_77112\zozdbc_ora_1548_i77112.trc
>   ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [12259], [], [], [], [],
>   [], [], [], [], [], [], []
>
> Trace file
>   d:\app\administrator\diag\rdbms\zozdbc\zozdbc\trace\zozdbc_ora_1548.trc
>   Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production Windows NT
>   Version V6.1 Service Pack 1  CPU                 : 4 - type 8664, 4
>   Physical Cores Process Affinity    : 0x0x0000000000000000 Memory
>   (Avail/Total): Ph:25008M/32767M, Ph+PgF:53887M/65533M  VM name
>   : VMWare Version (6) Instance name: zozdbc Redo thread mounted by this
>   instance: 1 Oracle process number: 47 Windows thread id: 1548, image:
>   ORACLE.EXE (SHAD)

And my trigger is belown,

```
    create or replace TRIGGER zoz_TABS.NIN_USER_DEF_TRGA
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON zoz_tabs.NIN_user_def
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   CURSOR c1 IS
      SELECT * FROM NIN_menu_def;

   CURSOR c2 IS
      SELECT m.menu_code,
             m.upper_menu,
             m.order_no,
             m.menu_label
        FROM (SELECT menu_code FROM NIN_menu_def
              MINUS
              SELECT menu_code
                FROM NIN_user_menu_def
               WHERE user_code = :NEW.USER_CODE) x,
             NIN_menu_def m
       WHERE m.menu_code = x.menu_code;
BEGIN
   IF (INSERTING) THEN
      FOR cc IN c1 LOOP
         INSERT INTO NIN_user_menu_def (user_code,
                                        menu_code,
                                        upper_menu,
                                        order_no,
                                        menu_label)
              VALUES (:new.user_code,
                      cc.menu_code,
                      cc.upper_menu,
                      cc.order_no,
                      cc.menu_label);
      END LOOP;

      ---
      --sifre tan?m bilgisi kullan?c?ya mail ile gonderilir.
      ---
      NIN_user_pwd_mail_prc ('INSERT',
                             :NEW.dil_kod,
                             :new.org_kod,
                             :new.ser_kod,
                             :new.user_type,
                             :new.user_code,
                             :new.user_name || ' ' || :new.user_surname,
                             :new.password,
                             :new.ik_kod);
     --
     --Yeni eklenen user icin default page tanimi yapiliyor.
     --                             
     CREATE_USER_DEFAULT_PAGE(:new.user_code,:new.user_type,:new.kullanilan_NINtem);
   END IF;

   IF (UPDATING) THEN
      IF (:NEW.USER_STATUS = 'ACTIVE' AND :OLD.USER_STATUS != 'ACTIVE')
      THEN
         FOR cc IN c2 LOOP
            INSERT INTO NIN_user_menu_def (user_code,
                                           menu_code,
                                           upper_menu,
                                           order_no,
                                           menu_label)
                 VALUES (:new.user_code,
                         cc.menu_code,
                         cc.upper_menu,
                         cc.order_no,
                         cc.menu_label);
         END LOOP;
      END IF;

      ---
      --sifre de?isikli?i islemi yap?ld???nda veya personel atamas? yap?ld???nda sifre tan?m bilgisi kullan?c?ya mail ile gonderilir.
      ---

      IF ((:OLD.password != :NEW.password) OR (:OLD.ik_kod != :NEW.ik_kod)) THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('ISLEM VAR');
         NIN_user_pwd_mail_prc ('UPDATE',
                                :NEW.dil_kod,
                                :new.org_kod,
                                :new.ser_kod,
                                :new.user_type,
                                :new.user_code,
                                :new.user_name || ' ' || :new.user_surname,
                                :new.password,
                                :new.ik_kod);
      END IF;
   END IF;
END;
```

After checking support oracle i have seen its a bug and unfortunately it shows no fixed only i need to opatch etc.

Am i missing something ? I am planning to increase sga and pga sizes cause i have free resource on my server and i am planning to full database istatistics.
Can someone gives advice anything else more please ?
Thanks,

Comment: Better to ask this on [Database Administrators Site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: thanks i redirect question to Database Administrator Site thanks for advice.